# Is Dioxin causing Diabetes Mellitus?

Tags: diabetes-mellitus, poison

1. Today I was watching a show on Discovery Science (Everything You Need to Know About). In that show they were talking about toxins and venom.
2. In that they mentioned **Dioxin** and its effect. And suddenly I heard the unexpected, that Dioxin damages Pancreas!!
3. Dioxin spreads due to contamination by food & mainly beef (as mentioned in the show).
4. It is produced mainly because of (chlorinated) burning of fossil fuel, coal,trees,**PVC**, plastic.
5. As there is a spike in the diabetes in recent years. And there was a increase in pollution from last few decades.

It looks like Dioxin is culprit which is lurking behind to attack people and causing Diabetes.

Am I thinking right?

Comment: Correlation is not causation.  There has, for instance, been a large increase in the consumption of soft drinks in recent years.  There's also been a large increase in the number of personal computers, and of solar panels on rooftops.  Of those four correlations (and there are many others), which is most plausibly linked to diabetes?

Comment: Valuable information:- https://www.who.int/news-room/fact-sheets/detail/dioxins-and-their-effects-on-human-health